# How to define Colspan and Rowspan when using iText 7 for .NET

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, itext7

I have WPF app and I want to implement colspan and rowspan in my code. I used iText version 7 for exporting the data into PDF. However I don't know how to define colspan or rowspan for `Cell` objects. Is there any way to solve this?

My goal is actually to create main header along with subheader in my table.

My Output:

[image]

Goal Output:

[image]

My code below:

```
using iText.IO.Font.Constants;
using iText.Kernel.Font;
using iText.Kernel.Geom;
using iText.Kernel.Pdf;
using iText.Layout;
using iText.Layout.Element;
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows;

namespace ITextPdf.UI
{
   public partial class MainWindow : Window
   {
      public MainWindow()
      {
         InitializeComponent();
      }

      private void Export_Btn(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
      {
         SaveFileDialog dlg = new SaveFileDialog
         {
            DefaultExt = ".pdf",
            Filter = "Adobe PDF Files(*.pdf)|*.pdf",
            FilterIndex = 1
         };

         string fileName = string.Empty;

         if (dlg.ShowDialog() == true)
         {
            fileName = dlg.FileName;

            PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(fileName);
            PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);

            PdfFont font = PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(StandardFonts.HELVETICA);
            PdfFont bold = PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(StandardFonts.HELVETICA_BOLD);

            Document document = new Document(pdf, PageSize.LETTER);
            document.SetMargins(20, 20, 20, 20);
            document.Add(new Paragraph("General Ledger")
               .SetTextAlignment(iText.Layout.Properties.TextAlignment.CENTER)
               .SetFontSize(18)
               .SetFont(bold)
               .SetMarginBottom(-8));
            document.Add(new Paragraph("Naawan, Misamis Oriental")
               .SetTextAlignment(iText.Layout.Properties.TextAlignment.CENTER)
               .SetFontSize(14)
               .SetFont(font)
               .SetMarginBottom(20));

            var table = new Table(new float[] { 80, 120, 80, 80, 80 });
            table.SetMinWidth(100)
               .SetHorizontalAlignment(iText.Layout.Properties.HorizontalAlignment.CENTER)
               .SetFontSize(10);
            table.AddHeaderCell("Date");
            table.AddHeaderCell("Particulars");
            table.AddHeaderCell("Debit");
            table.AddHeaderCell("Credit");
            table.AddHeaderCell("Total Amount");
            table.AddCell("1/1/17");
            table.AddCell("Beginning Balance");
            table.AddCell("100.00");
            table.AddCell("");
            table.AddCell("100.00");
            table.AddCell("");
            table.AddCell("");
            table.AddCell("");
            table.AddCell("300.00");
            table.AddCell("200.00");

            document.Add(table);
            document.Close();
            Process.Start(fileName);
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Looking at your code, I don't see you defining any colspan or rowspan. Looking at your code and the resulting PDF, I'd say that iText executes your code correctly. Also: you're using iText 7, and you mention `PdfPCell`. The class `PdfPCell` doesn't exist in iText 7. It's an iText 5 class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to adapt these lines:

```
table.AddHeaderCell("Date");
table.AddHeaderCell("Particulars");
table.AddHeaderCell("Debit");
table.AddHeaderCell("Credit");
table.AddHeaderCell("Total Amount");
```

And change them like this:

```
table.AddHeaderCell(new Cell(2, 1).Add(new Paragraph("Date")));
table.AddHeaderCell(new Cell(2, 1).Add(new Paragraph("Particulars")));
table.AddHeaderCell(new Cell(1, 3).Add(new Paragraph("Amount")));
table.AddHeaderCell("Debit");
table.AddHeaderCell("Credit");
table.AddHeaderCell("Amount");
```

Note that you originally mentioned the `PdfPCell` class, but that class no longer exists in iText 7. You need the `Cell` class as explained in the [tutorial](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-building-blocks/chapter-5-adding-abstractelement-objects-part-2).

Comment: It doens't work. It says cannot convert from string to iText.Layout.Element.IBlockElement

Comment: Now, it's working. Here is my solution.
-----------
instead of:
table.AddHeaderCell(new Cell(1, 3).Add("Amount"));
I changed it to:
table.AddHeaderCell(new Cell(1,3).Add(new Paragraph("Amount"));

Comment: I've updated my answer based on your comment. Please accept the answer since it helped you solve your problem.